# Replacement for Windows Live Movie Maker for combining images and audio (Windows 10)?

Tags: mp4, youtube, windows, windows-movie-maker

I want to combine some audio I recorded with an image (for uploading to YouTube).

Googling turned up "Windows Live Movie Maker" which appears to be more dead than alive, now, at least as far as Windows 10 is concerned.

Who can recommend a free software download (or web-based service) that will allow me to create this simple, You-Tube-uploadable file? All I want is for a single image to remain static during the entire playing of the audio file.

The audio file was created with Audacity and is, at present, available as an .m4a file (but could be converted to another format from within Audacity); the image file is a .jpg, but could of course also be saved to another format.

### UPDATE

I tried to figure it out using both of those links from the Upload page (Slideshow and Edit Video) and in neither case did I see how to combine and audio file and an image, and then convert that mashup to a video.

I found [this link](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1696878?topic=2888648&hl=en), which appeared promising initially, but wasn't of much help.

Answer (score 2):

It can be made directly on the YouTube website. Look at the "Upload" page at the bottom-right corner:
[image]

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. So I'm assuming the "Video Editor" allows you to upload an image and an audio file, and it does the mashup?

Comment: I think you need not "Video Editor", but "Slidshow".... But I didn't use eater. Just try it.

Comment: I'll see; since I only want to use one image, calling it a slideshow would be kind of bizarre.